# Do we need Ingress controller if we have our own api-gateway in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, api-gateway

Pretty much the title.

**API-Gateway** can do routing along with extra benefits ( Auth, logging, SSL termination etc etc).

Now, **Ingress** is mostly for routing - but, if we deploy **API-Gateway** as a service *in kubernetes cluster itself*, then API-gateway can access/route to other services via **ClusterIP** to other components.

Of course, an external facing load-balancer will be there to connect outside world to our API-Gateway

- then do we need Ingress separately ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the TheNewStack [post](https://thenewstack.io/api-gateway-ingress-controller-or-service-mesh-when-to-use-what-and-why/#:%7E:text=We%27ll%20make%20it%20simple,ingress%20controller%20or%20service%20mesh) by Jenn Gile;

> If you need API gateway functionality inside Kubernetes, it’s usually best to choose a tool that can be configured using native Kubernetes config tooling such as YAML. Typically, that’s an ingress controller or service mesh.But we hear you saying, “My API gateway tool has so many more features than my ingress controller (or service mesh). Aren’t I missing out?” No! More features do not equal better tools, especially within Kubernetes where tool complexity can be a killer.

An ingress controller makes one Kubernetes service that gets exposed as a LoadBalancer. For simple understanding, you can consider ingress as a Nginx server which just does the work of forwarding the traffic to services based on the ruleset. However, an ingress doesn't have much functionality like API gateway. Some ingresses don't support features such as authentication, rate limiting, application routing, security, merging response & request, and other add-ons/plugin options. While an API gateway can also do the work of simple routing but it mostly gets used when you need higher flexibility, security and configuration options.

An API gateway is used for application routing, rate limiting, security, request and response, handling and other application related tasks. Say, you have a microservice based application in which the request needs information to be collected from multiple microservices. You need a way to distribute the user requests to different services and gather the responses from all micro services and prepare the final response to be sent to the user. An API Gateway is the one which does this kind of work for you.

Using both an Ingress controller and an API gateway within Kubernetes can provide flexibility for organizations to achieve business.

You can also refer to this document on [How Do I Choose? Api gateway vs. Ingress controller](https://www.nginx.com/blog/how-do-i-choose-api-gateway-vs-ingress-controller-vs-service-mesh/) authored by Jenn Gile for more detailed information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

But what additional benefit an ingress controller brings, which API_Gateway did not ?

Comment: As mentioned above an ingress controller does the same job as a reverse proxy or an API gateway when it comes to handling incoming traffic and routing it to the appropriate server/Service. However, the ingress controller operates at a different level of the network stack.

Comment: the ingress controller is a specific type of reverse proxy designed to operate within Kubernetes clusters. Just as the API gateway sits at the edge of your infrastructure, the ingress controller sits at the edge of the cluster, listening for incoming traffic, and then routes it to the appropriate Kubernetes Service within the cluster